# DHTMLX Scheduler custom Timeline with AM/PM days

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I use the DHTMLX Scheduler in Timeline view for a project and the working hours are from 7AM to 5PM. I was able to make an AM/PM view per day but the first_hour and last_hour configs are not respected in the view. The screenshot shows more. The first event in the morning should be displayed far more left as it starts at 7:30Am.
[image]

My config:

```
scheduler.locale.labels.timeline_tab = "Timeline";
scheduler.locale.labels.section_custom = "Section";

scheduler.config.dblclick_create = false;
scheduler.config.edit_on_create = false;
scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick = false;
scheduler.config.details_on_create = false;
scheduler.config.start_on_monday = true;
scheduler.config.first_hour = 7;
scheduler.config.last_hour = 17;
scheduler.config.full_day = true;
scheduler.config.mark_now = false;

scheduler.config.drag_move = false;
scheduler.config.drag_resize = false;

//===============
//Configuration
//===============

scheduler.createTimelineView({
    name: "timeline",
    x_unit: "hour",
    x_date: "%A",
    x_step: 12,
    x_size: 14,
    x_start: 0,
    x_length: 14,
    y_unit: scheduler.serverList('teams'), // sections and events from same ajax call
    y_property: "team_id",
    render: "bar",
    section_autoheight: false,
    dy: 30,
    dx: 100,
    // first_hour: 7,
    // last_hour: 17,
    second_scale: {
        x_unit: "day", // unit which should be used for second scale
        x_date: "%D %j %M"
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
After update based on the answer here the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_hour`, `last_hour` configs applied for Y-axis in Day, Week, Units views (check [Documentation](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_first_hour_config.html)).

Currently, to hide hours at the beginning and end of the day in the Timeline view, you should have only 1 X-axis like in this [sample](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/11_scales/06_timeline_hours.html). I.e. visible part of the event is from 10 to 18 because of `first_hour`, `end_hour` properties of `createTimelineView` method. Check the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/q3u9wz).

There is also `ignore_[viewName]` [function](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_scales.html) which can be used to hide interval that equal to min step of the scale (12 hours in your case).

This could help solve your issue if set min `step = 6` (hours) and disable 6-7 AM and 5-6 PM by [addMarkedTimespan](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_addmarkedtimespan.html). I tried to create a snippet for you http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/46ba545ad , but found out that the second part of this condition `if(date.getHours() < 6 || date.getHours() > 17){` is not working correctly. The event can be created until 6 PM. We will fix it ASAP, but now I can't specify the exact time. I suggest you use the first way with 1 scale to solve the issue.

Comment: This helped me a lot thx. Indeed the condition <6 || >17 is not working correctly.